# Descomprimir archivo ZIP en Cordova

Tags: html, jquery, cordova, zip

Tengo una aplicación echa con `cordova` para `android`  en la cual quiero descomprimir un archivo `.ZIP`

Para ello utilice es siguiente codigo mas aparte el plugin  `cordova-plugin-zip` de cordova   pero al ejecutar me manda error y el texto: `"Oops, cannot decompress files"`

```js
myApp.onPageInit('actualizarApp', function (page) {  
 myApp.params.swipePanel = false;
 actualizar();
});





var phatZIP='127.0.0.1/archivo.zip';
var destino ='/storage/emulated/0/';
function actualizar(){
 $$('#btn-actualizar').on('click',function(){
      //alerta('Hola');
      processZip(phatZIP,destino);
  }); 
}


function processZip(phatZIP, destino){
    // Handle the progress event
    var progressHandler = function(progressEvent){
        var percent =  Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

        // Display progress in the console : 8% ...
        console.log(percent + "%");
    };

    // Proceed to unzip the file
    window.zip.unzip(phatZIP, destino, (status) => {
        if(status == 0){
            console.log("Files succesfully decompressed");
        }

        if(status == -1){
            console.error("Oops, cannot decompress files");
        }
    }, progressHandler);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left"><a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Atrás</span></a></div><br>
    <div class="center sliding" style="font-size: 13px;"><div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">layers</i></div>Actualizar Aplicación</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pages">
  <div data-page="actualizarApp" class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block-title" style="margin-top:12px;"></div>
      <div class="list-block">
        <div class="content-block-title" style="text-align:center">Información de la Aplicación</div>
        <div class="content-block-inner">
        
          
          <p><a href="#" id="btn-actualizar" class="button button-big btn-login">Actualizar</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Te falla en un emulador o en un dispositivo? ¿Qué ves en la consola? ¿Ves algún progreso o algún mensaje de error? ¿Has verificado que tengas acceso al fichero y al directorio donde quieres descomprimir?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es en un dispositivo un Samsung S7, en consola solo aparece el texto `Oops, cannot decompress files`, si, si tengo acceso al `.zip`  de echo pase el archivo a mi dispositivo en almacenamiento interno y cambie la ruta por `file:///storage/emulated/0/archivo.zip` y de igual manera no lo hace.   
me guié utilizando este ejemplo 
[https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/513/how-to-unzip-decompress-zip-files-in-cordova]

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en consola me marca el siguiente error:  
`Oops, cannot decompress files
window.zip.unzip @ actualizarApp.js:34
fail @ zip.js:24
callbackFromNative @ cordova.js:293
(anonymous) @ VM76:1`